# forwardRef and i18 doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, react-i18next, react-forwardref

I want to get a ref of span tag of my ChildComponent which wrapped in translate from i-18.
But instead of  element forwardRef returns Translate Object from i18.
What should I do to receive ref of an element from a ChildComponent?
i18 version 8.4.3

```
const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
         ...
         return (
            <span ref={ref} ...></span>
            ...
         )
         ...
}
export default translate('translations', {forwardRef: true})(ChildComponent);
```